# Create new array sorted by number

Tags: javascript, sorting, numbers, parent-child, createelement

How do I create new elements and sort order by numbers from "data-number"? Any idea how to do it? I found a [sort method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) with, but how to insert in for loop?

The result in "parent-sort" should look like:

```
<div id="parent-sort">
    <div class="child" id="child2" data-name="1">1</div>
    <div class="child" id="child4" data-name="2">2</div>
    <div class="child" id="child1" data-name="3">3</div>
    <div class="child" id="child3" data-name="4">4</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    elementsort = document.getElementById("parent").children;
    for (i = 0; i < elementsort.length; i++) {
    var element_id = elementsort[i].id;
    var element_class_name = elementsort[i].className;
    var element_inner_html = elementsort[i].innerHTML;
    var data_name = elementsort[i].getAttribute("data-name");
    
    const new_div = document.createElement("div");
    new_div.id = element_id;
    new_div.className = element_class_name;
    new_div.innerText = element_inner_html;
    new_div.setAttribute("data-name", data_name);
    document.getElementById("parent-sort").appendChild(new_div);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child" id="child1" data-name="3">3</div>
    <div class="child" id="child2" data-name="1">1</div>
    <div class="child" id="child3" data-name="4">4</div>
    <div class="child" id="child4" data-name="2">2</div>
</div>

<div id="parent-sort">
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  elementsort = document.getElementById("parent").children;
  const sortedList = [...elementsort].sort((a, b) => {
    const c = a.textContent,
      d = b.textContent;
    return c < d ? -1 : c > d ? 1 : 0;
  });
  for (const item of sortedList) {
    document.getElementById("parent-sort").appendChild(item);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="child1" data-name="3">3</div>
  <div class="child" id="child2" data-name="1">1</div>
  <div class="child" id="child3" data-name="4">4</div>
  <div class="child" id="child4" data-name="2">2</div>
</div>

<div id="parent-sort">
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In your code, it sorts the order via innerHTML. I need to sort through the order of the numbers from "data-name". I changed c = a.textContent, to c = a.getAttribute ("data-name"). Is this a good approach?

Comment: @maja Yes, you can change textContent with another attribute, best regards

Comment: It seems that this formula works up to 10, if I add the number "div class =" child "id =" child23 "data-name =" 24 "> 24 </div> then it recognizes 2 out of 24, and puts it in second place. What should I change in the formula so that it recognizes above 10?